# AWS Lambda - Inject Spring Bean in Spring Boot Handler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lambda, aws-lambda

I have uploaded a simple Spring Boot project to Amazon Lambda and I am currently trying to test it.
It works 100% but I get a null pointer when I try to inject a Spring Bean
Here is my code for the LambdaHandler

```
package com.test.services.lambda;

import java.util.Calendar;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.test.services.MyServices;

public class MyLambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<String, String> {

    public MyLambdaFunctionHandler() {
    }


    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext springContext;
    private MyServices myServices;

    public String handleRequest(String input, Context lambdaContext) {
        this.myServices = springContext.getBean(MyServices.class);
        lambdaContext.getLogger().log("AWS Request ID: " + lambdaContext.getAwsRequestId());
        lambdaContext.getLogger().log("Input: " + input + " at " + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
        myServices.sendGoodMessage("Message sent from Lambda");
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

I set the handler in Amazon  Lambda to be the following

```
com.test.services.lambda.MyLambdaFunctionHandler::handleRequest
```

However when I test this function - I get this error message

```
{
  "errorMessage": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
  "errorType": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "com.test.services.lambda.MyLambdaFunctionHandler.handleRequest(SlackLambdaFunctionHandler.java:23)",
    "com.test.services.lambda.MyLambdaFunctionHandler.handleRequest(SlackLambdaFunctionHandler.java:12)"
  ]
}
```

It is failing where I inject the Spring Bean
Can anyone offer any advice on how I can go about injecting a spring bean into my AWS Lambda Handler?

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated

Thanks
Damien

Comment: Could you finally resolve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to inject `ApplicationContext`.

Yours should work as long as spring manage your beans. Did you declare `MyLambdaFunctionHandler` in some `@Configuration` file as a `@Bean`?

Did you use `new MyLambdaFunctionHandler()` somewhere to initialize it outside spring `@Configuration`? (this means spring is not managing your bean).

If spring does not manage your bean it cannot inject beans into it.

If not, it should be annotated with `@Component` and scanned by some `@ComponentScan`.

If it is declared, you should use spring `ApplicationContextAware` to set your `ApplicationContext`. Spring got a lot of those utility interfaces to inject some of its core classes to your beans.

example:

```
public class MyLambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<String, String>, ApplicationContextAware {

    public MyLambdaFunctionHandler() {
    }

    private ApplicationContext springContext;
    private MyServices myServices;

    public String handleRequest(String input, Context lambdaContext) {
        this.myServices = springContext.getBean(MyServices.class);
        lambdaContext.getLogger().log("AWS Request ID: " + lambdaContext.getAwsRequestId());
        lambdaContext.getLogger().log("Input: " + input + " at " + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
        myServices.sendGoodMessage("Message sent from Lambda");
        return "Hello World";
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.springContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did it work for you? How exactly spring config file is going to be injected?

Comment: @KuldeepYadav, another thing you can do is adding `private static ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(MySpringApplication.class);` and use it instead of injecting it as AWS lambda usually does not have spring application running. The downside using spring in this case is cold starts might take a long time

Comment: I tried something like this: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/tarkshala/8eM9Ek
It is working. Only bad thing that is happening is with each handler call applicationContext is initialized and bean creation happens all over again for each handler call.

Comment: Change `applicationContext` to be static outside of the `handleRequest` code (also initialize it outside of the `handleReques` code) and it will be loaded once each cold start - first call initialize then the others reuse until AWS clear the instance if it was not called for x amount of time

Comment: Thanks it worked. Does aws unloads lambda function if not invoked for sometime? In my case there are going to be 10 requests per day.

Comment: Yes, there is a concept of cold and hot start. When you do not call the function for some time (need to look at docs for exact behavior), AWS will timeout the function and next call will be like the first one.

Comment: You are right. Lambda removes application from memory when left unused for ampule time. I just checked this behavior with my service. Looks like I will have to stick with Tomcat(Servlet Container) thing.

Comment: If you use `spring-boot` you can use a fat spring boot JAR to build docker containers for example and use other more modern ways of deployment, but this is up to you :)

Comment: how to inject properties into handler though @Value annotation?

Comment: @SumanthVarada unfortunately with this setup you can't because the handler is not managed by spring. You can use `springContext` to extract the environment and get your properties from there.