# Micronaut equivalence of Spring ApplicationContextAware

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aws-lambda, micronaut, applicationcontext

In Spring Boot, we have `ApplicationContextAware` interface, providing a way to set `ApplicationContext`, which is then used to inject some beans (that can only be initiated by the programme) into the class

```
// this is a Spring Boot programme
package com.example.demo

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;

public class MyClass implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private MyBean myBean;
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext= applicationContext;
    }

    public void setBean(){
       this.myBean= applicationContext.getBean(MyBean.class);
    }
}
```

I was trying to find such a method in `Micronaut` framework. I looked into documentation and tried a few classes like `ApplicationContextConfigurer`, `ApplicationContextBuilder` etc. but none seemed to work

By looking at what the code above does, is there a way to achieve the same thing in Micronaut?

---

More background:

I deployed a Micronaut application onto AWS Lambda and got NullPointerException. I referred to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43079856/aws-lambda-inject-spring-bean-in-spring-boot-handler), which mentioned ApplicationContextAware. This post uses Spring, but I suspect the underlysing mechanism should be similar

---

Posting my pom.xml, as asked by the comments

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>MicronautExp</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <packaging>${packaging}</packaging>

  <parent>
    <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
    <artifactId>micronaut-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.4</version>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <jdk.version>11</jdk.version>
    <release.version>11</release.version>
    <micronaut.version>3.7.4</micronaut.version>
    <micronaut.runtime>netty</micronaut.runtime>
    <micronaut.runtime>lambda</micronaut.runtime>
    <exec.mainClass>com.example.Application</exec.mainClass>
    <exec.mainClass>io.micronaut.function.aws.runtime.MicronautLambdaRuntime</exec.mainClass>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.test</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-test-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.24</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

<!--    micronaut http dependencies. Forgot why they are here, but better not touch it-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-http-client</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-http-server-netty</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

<!--    graalvm compilers. Forgot why they are here, but better not touch it-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.graalvm.nativeimage</groupId>
      <artifactId>svm</artifactId>
      <version>22.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.graalvm.sdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>graal-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>22.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

<!--    micronaut email dependency-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.email</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-email-javamail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.email</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-email</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

<!--    AWS Lambda dependencies-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.aws</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-function-aws-api-proxy</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.aws</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-function-aws-api-proxy-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.aws</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-function-aws-custom-runtime</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.micronaut.build</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <!-- Uncomment to enable incremental compilation -->
          <!-- <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation> -->

          <annotationProcessorPaths combine.children="append">
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-http-validation</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
            </path>
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.group=com.example</arg>
            <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.module=MicronautExp</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: hello you can put the import section please.

Comment: @devskillup could u elaborate on what do u mean by "put the import section"?

Comment: the import of classes. like this : import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.NewTopic;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

Comment: @devskillup done. this is the only import in this code

Comment: you can put your pom.xml also please

Comment: @devskillup sorry do you mean pom.xml of my Micronaut project? The Spring sample code is copied from (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43079856/aws-lambda-inject-spring-bean-in-spring-boot-handler), I do not have a copy of the actual Spring project.

Comment: @devskillup my micronaut pom.xml is added. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Micronaut you don't need such an interface.  If any Micronaut managed bean accepts the `ApplicationContext` as a constructor parameter, or includes a property marked with `@Inject`, the `ApplicationContext` will be injected.

Ex:

```
import io.micronaut.context.ApplicationContext;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.*;

@Controller("/demo")
public class DemoController {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public DemoController(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Get(uri="/", produces="text/plain")
    public String index() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: btw... I know you didn't ask about this part, but there may not be any good reason to have that `setBean` method like you showed in your `MyClass` class.  In both Spring and Micronaut it would be better to let the DI container initialize the `myBean` property.

Comment: Thank you. I had a look at some other sources days ago, and yes I agree that ApplicationContext can be generated by itself without the method I provided

Comment: "and yes I agree that ApplicationContext can be generated by itself without the method I provided" - I wasn't saying that the ApplicationContect can be generated by itself.  I am saying that you could let the dependency injection engine initialize `myBean` instead of doing that imperatively yourself.